# Chrome 67 Date определяет неверный часовой пояс

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, дата, datetime

Стал замечать, что Chrome после обновления стал определять московский часовой пояс как-то странно:

[image: screenshot]

Как это исправить?

Comment: А в настройках винды точно правильный выбран? Что другие браузеры (и приложения говорят)?

Comment: С другой стороны в JS всё равно нет настоящих таймзон. Можно только получить сдвиг относительно UTC

Comment: IE показывает правильный пояс, Opera то же что и Chrome, а FF просто время, без часового пояса.
Такой часовой пояс явно намеренно выводится... Хотя раньше выводилось верно.